Sum of Value between Slicer Dates
I want to get the sum between two slicer dates without breaking it out by month. The number should be static for the dates selected.
Here's an example of the data I'm trying to get information from:



Date
Disposal Method
Weight (lb)




1/1/2024
Recycle
150


1/1/2024
Landfill
100


2/1/2024
Recycle
225


2/1/2024
Landfill
175


3/1/2024
Recycle
125


3/1/2024
Landfill
75


TOTAL

850






Date
Production (lbs)




1/1/24
750


2/1/24
500


3/1/24
75


TOTAL
1,325



I have a _Calendar table for 1/1/24 - 12/31/24.
I want to get the landfill intensity (landfill lbs/production lbs to be dynamic with a date slicer. If the dates selected were 1/1/2024 - 2/28/24. The static intensity should be (100 [Jan landfill] + 175 [Feb landfill]) / (750 [Jan Prod] + 500 [Feb Prod]) = 0.22
I'm trying to get the following table:



Date
Landfill Intensity of Dates Selected




1/1/24
0.22


2/1/24
0.22



I've tried this:
Landfill_Intensity = 
    CALCULATE(
        sum('Waste'[Weight (lbs)]),
            'Waste'[Disposal Method] = "landfill",
            DATESBETWEEN('Waste'[Date],FIRSTDATE(_Calendar[Date]),LASTDATE(_Calendar[Date]))      
    )    

/

CALCULATE(
    sum(Production[Weight (lbs)]), 
        DATESBETWEEN(Production[Date], FIRSTDATE(_Calendar[Date]),LASTDATE(_Calendar[Date]))
    )

and the intensity is still dependent on date:



Date
Landfill Intensity of Dates Selected




1/1/24
0.13 [100/750]


2/1/24
0.35 [175/500]



How can I make the intensity take values in the slicer but apply a static value for values within the date slicer?

Can you try this below-
Landfill_Intensity = 


CALCULATE(
    sum('Waste'[Weight (lb)]),
    'Waste'[Disposal Method] = "landfill",
    DATESBETWEEN(
        'Waste'[Date],
        FIRSTDATE('calendar'[Date]),
        LASTDATE('calendar'[Date])
    )        
)    

/

CALCULATE(
    sum(Production[Production (lbs)]), 
    FILTER(
        ALL(Production[Date]),
        Production[Date] >= FIRSTDATE('calendar'[Date])
            && Production[Date] <= LASTDATE('calendar'[Date])
        
    )
)
        

Output-

Hope your Production and Waste tables are connected to _calendar table this below way using Date column-

